# Scroll to element works in console but not in code

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm using this code to find a row in a table and then scroll that row to the top of the viewport:

```
$('html, body').animate({ 
    scrollTop: $('label:contains("' +textToFind+ '")').parents('tr').offset().top 
}, 1000);
```

This works properly in the js console if I replace "textToFind" with a known valid label text. But it does not work in my script. All other jquery in the script is working and I've tested over and over that the row is being properly selected in the code (outputting to the console).

What can I be missing here?

Comment: You miss nothing, your code is correct. Show us the rest of your code

Comment: Your code is correct (that's why it works in the console). Are you sure your DOM is ready and those elements exist when you execute this `.animate()`?

Comment: I just realized a highlight effect I have on the same row isn't working either. This is executing inside of an $.ajax success function, **after** the table rows are added from within a javascript function, so maybe that's the issue. How can I get around this (if at all)?

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in my comment, I'm running this animation within the success function of an ajax call. Moving the line of code in question to the function that calls the ajax call resolved the issue and correctly scrolled to the desired row.